# Firebase Cloud Functions. Cannot read property parent of undefined (.ref)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to deploy the following function to firebase. The function deploys fine, but when the function triggers I get an error: `cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`. The error occurs in the first line I reference parent. I used console.log on snapshot and snapshot.ref, and although snapshot exists, snapshot.ref is undefined.

I have used snapshot.ref.parent in other cloud functions and it is working fine. There are two main difference with this function:
(a) it is an onUpdate (I have previously been using onCreate and onDelete)
(b) it is an async function.

```
exports.likeRating = functions.database.ref('Ocean/{waveId}/Likes').onUpdate(async (snapshot) =>{
    let likes; let dislikes; let comments; let echoes;

    await snapshot.ref.parent.child('Dislikes').once('value').then(response=>{dislikes = response.val(); return null});
    await snapshot.ref.parent.child('Likes').once('value').then(response=>{likes = response.val(); return null});
    await snapshot.ref.parent.child('Comments').child('CommentsCount').once('value').then(response=>{comments = response.val(); return null});
    await snapshot.ref.parent.child('Echoes').once('value').then(response=>{echoes = response.val(); return null});

    snapshot.ref.parent.child('Rating').set(dislikes+likes+comments+echoes);
    return null;

}
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function will run significantly slower than it needs to as you're waiting for your requests in series, you should await a `Promise.all([<Promises>])` instead, also the `return null` is redundant.

I'm also not sure why you add everything up each time instead of incrementing the Rating value but maybe I didn't think about it as much as you.

If you look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentBuilder#onUpdate) the signature of the callback is `function(non-null functions.Change containing non-null functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot, optional non-null functions.EventContext)`

So the first param is [change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change.html) which contains `before` and `after` which are of type `DocumentSnapshot`, it is those properties you should be using e.g. `change.after.ref`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dominic. I rewrote my code and it works. The reason I choose to add instead of increment is because I'm a total noob XD. On a sort of related note. In a different section of my code I have nested promises (.then) and I get a warning about doing so - is there a better method, i.e. should I be using async await or is there another function like Promise.all I am unaware of?